# Return multiple PHP->MySQL queries to Angularjs $scope arrays not working

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ajax

I have my angular controller excecuting a PHP file that pulls data from my db, and originally it only pulled one query, put it in a scope array, and I successfully put that data on the web page.

Now I'm executing 2 queries in the file, each one their own array, inside a parent array loading into the angular controller, then separated to two $scope arrays.  Now I can't load them on the page.

Here's the files.

```
$http.get("/xxxxx/controller/recieve_data.php?my_id=10001&contact_id=10002")
    .success(function(data)
    {
       $scope.data_sent = data.data_sent;
       $scope.data_recieved = data.data_recieved;
    })
    .error(function() 
    {
       $scope.data = "error in fetching data";
    });
```

The PHP file:

```
$data_sent = array();

while ($row_sent = mysqli_fetch_array($result_sent)) 
{
  $data_sent[] = $row_sent;
}

$data_recieved = array();

while ($row_recieved = mysqli_fetch_array($result_recieved))
{
  $data_recieved[] = $row_recieved;
}

$data = array();

$data['data_sent'] = $data_sent;

$data['data_recieved'] = $data_recieved;

print json_encode($data);
```

The Chrome Network Console shows me all the data was successfully pulled from the db and brought over through the AJAX, so I think what is wrong is something involving putting the data into the scope arrays.

UPDATE: In the HTML I'm writing `'ng-repeat="x in data_sent"`

Answer (score 0):

Modify the success function like the following

```
.success(function(response)
{
  $scope.data_sent = response.data.data_sent;
  $scope.data_recieved = response.data.data_recieved;
})
```

Comment: Still no dice.  The object in 'response' is the object I passed over, which is the parent array, so technically if I was to put response in the parameter, it'd still have to be response.data_sent

Comment: can you comment the response you got on console

Comment: Consoles empty, if you're referring to the network one, it returned the arrays of each row from the DB

Comment: can you add the `console.log(data);` inside success function and comment that data ?

Comment: It will not console log anything in the success function. Not even 'hello'